# Have you ever used SerializationSurrogate and why you need this?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I'm a little confused about `ISerializationSurrogate` and when it may be necessary. So, if you used it, what goal have you been achivieng?

Answer (score 1):

The `ISerializationSurrogate` can be used to control the serialisation of an object. On some occasions I have used it to make the on wire representation more compact. For example turning

```
 Size: {
   Width: 20,
   Height: 30
 }
```

into

```
 Size: 20x30
```

Other uses may include enabling immutable objects to be serialized/de serialized.

Answer (score 1):

ISerializationSurrogate is my go-to way to (de)serialize (a List of) objects contained in a closed assembly that weren't marked `[Serializable]` and can't be modified.

The only alternative to achieve this is to manually construct your XML nodes one property at a time, which can be tedious.  Now I write a class file per object to be serialized, and map the properties of my choosing.  The rest happens automagically, as you can map these Surrogate classes using a `SurrogateSelector`.  Common classes (like List) are serialized out of the box.

Another use is the one described by Colin Bull in the other answer.